# Sweet Alert for Laravel 5.4 Error: Class '‘Alerts' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sweetalert

I'm trying to install the Sweet Alert package for Laravel: https://github.com/socieboy/alerts. I'm using Laravel 5.4.

I've followed all the directions exactly as outlined on the GitHub page, but I'm getting an error when I try to load any page that uses the master.blade.php template: "Class '‘Alerts' not found."

Has anyone else run into this? Is this package not compatible with v5.4?

Also, it seems like there is another Sweet Alert package for Laravel: https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert Does one replace the other? Is there any difference between the two?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show code also show the code of app.php @Brian

Comment: Sure, I added this line: 
Socieboy\Alerts\AlertServiceProvider::class,
to the providers array under the Package Service Providers section

Comment: Dear, I cannot solve this issue without seeing your code. So can you put some code snaps where you have used this package functions. @Brain

Comment: Okay lets solve it blindly! Did you added @include('Alerts::show') right after the JS script file? @Brain

Comment: @PassionInfinite, thanks for your help. I think I figured out what the problem was. It had something to do with how some of my header partials were being pulled in. Fixed the formatting of those, and now everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

The error had to do with how some partials for my header were being pulled in. Nothing to do with Sweet Alert. Problem solved.